# Excel - manually modifying value in a ListObject totals row causes problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I found the following issue when working with ListObject (table) in Excel.

Let's say I got the following:

- a table with three columns, A, B, C, all numbers
- column C being calculated as a simple A*B, i.e. `=[@A]*[@B]`
- a totals row where column C is summed up, i.e. `=SUBTOTAL(109;[C])`
- that totals value being referenced from elsewhere, i.e. a sheet summarizing the totals, as `=Table1[[#Totals];[C]]`

Imagine a table where amounts and prices are multiplied and then summed up as a total price.

All works fine as long as one does not do the following:

- change the value of the totals field manually, i.e. replace the `=SUBTOTAL(109;[C])` by e.g. 500

If you do that, then the following happens:

- the value shown in the totals field and the cell where it is referenced is no longer aligned as before - i.e. it switched from right aligned to left aligned, this is how we figured out something is happening
- the value is ignored by e.g. SUM functions

The reason why the manual change happens is because of users who are brute-forcing the values to be like they want them (e.g. a "nice xxx,00 €" price instead of "xxx,yz €", they do it how and where they think they should do this, and I have no power to tell them not to do that.

There is nothing obviously different in the working and the non-working states. Has anyone encountered this and knows why this is happening and if there is anything I can do to prevent this from happening to make the whole thing more robust, even if manual changes are done where they shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't access to the materials that would resolve the truth of the variations I see when experimenting here, so all I shall say about WHAT is happening is that for whatever reason Excel is treating the manual entry as text.

However, it is still able to be used by Excel as a number and in various ways so you can pick the solution that you like best.

The simplest way is simply not available. That would be to not insert a Totals row, but rather to just enter the formula (or a different one) by hand. But even a simple `SUM()` entered the row after the Table ends convinces Excel to change the row to a Totals row and give you the same issue. Thanks Excel, right?

If it were you using it and you had full freedom in what to do, you could force ("coerce" in Excel-speak) Excel to still treat the entry as a number by remembering to enter an `=` first (so `=500` not `500`). All good. But you aren't, so you have to do the coercing "downstream" of the cell the user changes.

A way to do that would be to change your downstream formula/s to not take their value from that cell and formula, but rather to take the sum anew in themselves. There are theoretical reasons not to do this, one revolving around the idea of inadvertent mismatching of values that are supposed to be the same, but the only important thing about it here is that they will catch on and start wrecking your work elsewhere, perhaps worse than now.

So you need to accept their messing with that spot since the only problem now is that they do it and it messes things up downstream, not that they damage the structure of the spreadsheet itself. That means continuing to reference that cell where you do and fixing the problem there, downstream. You don't mention it, but I'm sure you've realized, or they've said it, that they will start wrecking it there too if they can't change things as they do now and see the proper effect of their changes.

Fortunately this can easily be done. The absolute simplest way is:

```
=Table1[[#Totals],[C]]*1
```

or
=Table1[[#Totals],[C]]+0

That's all it takes. You could use `VALUE()` wrapped around the reference instead (that is, the whole thing since it is a single reference, not a combination of a couple references). That might seem easier for maintenance. Any of these are simple, quick, straightforward.

```
=VALUE(Table1[[#Totals],[C]])
```

Anytime you see the alignment shift you observed Excel is treating the cell's contents as text rather than as a numeric value. When that happens you can either address it directly (when possible, not here of course) by fixing the basic entry in whichever of a half dozen ways work, or by handling it downstream, perhaps as suggested above.

Comment: I like the VALUE() approach, as both *1 and +0 have the potential to be "interpreted" by the users and changed in unpredictable ways, whereas VALUE() might be something they won't touch because it is beyond their Excel experience.

Answer (score 0):

Any manual entering of a value in the field replaces the formula with
a fixed value.

There is no solution, except reloading the worksheet to re-establish
the formula.

Or perhaps replacing this field by two fields, one computed and the other
manually alterable.

Comment: It's not so much about whether there is a formula there or not, but about the effect this - seemingly small - change has. There is something changing aspects like alignment (which made it noticeable,), and something which, while still appearing to be a number, makes the value ignored in e.g. sums. It still works fine in plain =Table1[[#Totals];[C]]+y formulas, by the way. I'd like to know if this is a bug in Excel, or intentional, or happening for an unknown reason.

Comment: It's certainly not a bug. How would you like a manually entered value to become again a formula? The external reference probably still uses the computation as it was when it was created. These are all related to the implementation in Excel, which is not always evident as to how it works.

Comment: I don't expect it to become a formula again - but I expect a field's effective value to behave basically the same, whether it is the result of a formula evaluation or entered manually.

Comment: Excel does as Excel does. We can't control it, only adapt to it. You could add formatting to the field for a specific format.